# PHP Mysql query data not correct

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie Programmer here, I want to know why my code does not get the correct data from my Mysql DB.

```
mysql_connect('localhost',"root","password");
mysql_select_db("Torch");
$playerbal = mysql_query("SELECT money FROM table WHERE name = '$player'");
```

If I use this code, then I get the $playerbal as **Resource id #7**

I have found some solutions for this Resouce id #7 error. If I use **mysql_fetch_array**, I get just **"Array"**

Comment: **If I used mysql_fetch_array, I got just "Array"**, so now, what's wrong with the array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have corrected your English in the post.  Please edit your post and tell us what you are expecting to get.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_* functions are now deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.
Your code isn't working because you need to use mysqli_fetch_array() in order to retrieve the actual data in the table using a DB connection handler
Try using something like this :

```
//Create DB connection 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","Torch");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT money FROM table WHERE name = '$player'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 

//Retrieve the info(row) from the retrieved recordset and loop through it
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

  //Retrieve the needed field from the row
  $data=$row['money'];

  //do your stuff here

}

//Close connection
mysqli_close($con);
```

BTW Don't forget to sanitize your inputs.

Comment: Thanks This one really helped me!

Comment: NP. If this helped, selecting this as the answer would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() statement returns a resource pointer to the result set, not the data itself. You'll need to use mysql_fetch_array() in order to retrieve the actual data in the table.

here's the sol

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($playerbal);
$data = $row['money'];
echo $data;
```

Comment: Thanks, It really helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all rows of money column then use this code-

```
mysql_connect('localhost',"root","password");
mysql_select_db("Torch");
$playerbal = mysql_query("SELECT money FROM table WHERE name = '{$player}'");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($playerbal)){
      echo $data[0];  //there is only one column so this column is stored into 0 index.

}
```